# Can I automatically share it to other API, whatever I post on Facebook Page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, share

I am looking for something like `Link to Twitter` feature. But now I need to link to my own website API, whenever I write a new post on my facebook page (**via website**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `webhooks` for this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks

Whenever you post something, the webhook will get called and you can post on your website.